# Add linebreak in column titles in sankey diagram in R

Tags: javascript, r, svg, d3.js, networkd3

I would like to ask whether can I add line break to the title column in sankey diagram generated by `sankeyNetwork()`? The title added by using  `htmlwidgets::onRender.`

Please find my data and code as below:

Data used to links:

```
sali1 <- structure(list(source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), levels = c("Yes", "I have heard something about it", "No", 
"I don't no/No answer"), class = "factor"), target = c("Strongly Disagree ", 
"Disagree ", "Neither agree, nor disagree ", "Agree ", "Strongly Agree ", 
"I don't know/No answer ", "Strongly Disagree ", "Disagree ", 
"Neither agree, nor disagree ", "Agree ", "Strongly Agree ", 
"I don't know/No answer ", "Strongly Disagree ", "Disagree ", 
"Neither agree, nor disagree ", "Agree ", "Strongly Agree ", 
"I don't know/No answer ", "Disagree ", "Neither agree, nor disagree ", 
"Agree ", "Strongly Agree ", "I don't know/No answer "), value = c(32L, 
84L, 101L, 162L, 31L, 2L, 20L, 83L, 419L, 479L, 60L, 20L, 9L, 
16L, 134L, 152L, 31L, 151L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 12L), group = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "I-have-heard-something-about-it", 
"I-have-heard-something-about-it", "I-have-heard-something-about-it", 
"I-have-heard-something-about-it", "I-have-heard-something-about-it", 
"I-have-heard-something-about-it", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "I-dont-no/No-answer", "I-dont-no/No-answer", "I-dont-no/No-answer", 
"I-dont-no/No-answer", "I-dont-no/No-answer"), IDsource = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3), IDtarget = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(source = structure(1:4, levels = c("Yes", 
"I have heard something about it", "No", "I don't no/No answer"
), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:6, 7:12, 13:18, 
    19:23), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Data for nodes

```
nodes <- structure(list(name = c("Yes", "I have heard something about it", 
"No", "I don't no/No answer", "Strongly Disagree ", "Disagree ", 
"Neither agree, nor disagree ", "Agree ", "Strongly Agree ", 
"I don't know/No answer "), group = c("Yes", "I-have-heard-something-about-it", 
"No", "I-dont-no/No-answer", "Strongly-Disagree-", "Disagree-", 
"Neither-agree,-nor-disagree-", "Agree-", "Strongly-Agree-", 
"I-dont-know/No-answer-")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code for plotting sankey:

```
# Manually change color
color_scale <- "d3.scaleOrdinal() .domain(['Yes', 'I-have-heard-something-about-it', 'No','I-dont-no/No-answer', 'Strongly-Disagree-','Disagree-', 'Neither-agree,-nor-disagree-', 'Agree-', 'Strongly-Agree-', 'I-dont-know/No-answer-']) .range(['#28C4A9', '#A0C982', '#857A6E', '#bebebe', '#857A6E', '#D5B252', '#00487F', '#A0C982', '#28C4A9', '#bebebe']); "

# Plot sankey
sankey_sali1 <- sankeyNetwork(Links = sali1, Nodes = nodes,
                              Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                              sinksRight = FALSE,
                              colourScale = color_scale,
                              NodeGroup = "group",
                              LinkGroup = "group",
                              nodeWidth = 40, fontSize = 20,
                              fontFamily = "Arial",
                              nodePadding = 20,
                              iterations = 0,
                              margin = list(left = 1, right = 1, top = 40, bottom = 10))

# Apply the manual var labels and change font of the labels
sankey_sali1 <- htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey_sali1, '
    function(el, x) { 
        var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes()
            .map(d => d.x)
            .filter((v, i, a) => a
            .indexOf(v) === i)
            .sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        var labels = ["Do you know anything about radon?", "Radon may be a problem, but I have not paid much attention to it"];
        cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
        d3.select(el)
            .select("svg")
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", d)
            .attr("y", 25)
            .text(labels[i])
            .style("font-family", "Arial")
            .style("font-size", "23");
        })
      }
    ')
  
sankey_sali1
```

Current output: [image]

As you can see, the label for the right column "Radon may be a problem, but I have not paid much attention to it" has overflowed from the picture. I would like to add a line break to it, after "problem, " in order for it to stay in the frame

Comment: Have you tried changing `problem,` to `problem,\n` or `problem,<br>`?

Comment: Yes. `\n` the title did not show up, and `<br>` does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

For an SVG, multi-line text needs to be split up and put into separate `<tspan>` tags. This is not elegant, but demonstrates a solution...

```r
sankey_sali1 <- htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey_sali1, '
    function(el, x) { 
        var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes()
            .map(d => d.x)
            .filter((v, i, a) => a
            .indexOf(v) === i)
            .sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
        var labels = ["Do you know anything \\nabout radon?", "Radon may be a problem, but I \\nhave not paid much attention to it"];
        cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
          var textnode = d3.select(el)
              .select("svg")
              .append("text")
              .attr("x", d)
              .attr("y", 25)
              .style("font-family", "Arial")
              .style("font-size", "23");
          var lines = labels[i].split(/\\r?\\n/);
          textnode.append("tspan").text(lines[0]);
          textnode.append("tspan").text(lines[1]).attr("x", d).attr("dy", "1em");
        })
      }
    ')

sankey_sali1
```